# Compare 2 XSD files and add missing elements from file 2 to file 1

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, xsd, lodash

My requirement is to compare 2 XSD files (file1.xsd and file2.xsd) which has a nested structure. I need to add the missing elements from file2 to file1 (Assuming file1 is the base and additional elements need to be added from file2 to the base i.e. file1.

I was thinking of converting the xsd to json and then using some mergeWith function from lodash to combine and then convert back to xsd. Does that idea seem to work ?

providing the sample input files and required output.

file1.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="child1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="child2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="grandchild1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="grandchild2" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

file2.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="child1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="child2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="grandchild1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="grandchild3" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

required output.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="child1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="child2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="grandchild1" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="grandchild2" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="grandchild3" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

As you can see, the grandchild3 which was missing in file1.xsd (base) was added to file1 from file2 after comparison.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to able to find solution on my own. Please find the solution for the above question.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const path = require('path');

const pre = 'xs';

let schema = `${pre}:schema`;
let element = `${pre}:element`;
let complexType = `${pre}:complexType`;
let sequence = `${pre}:sequence`;

// Read the XSD files
const file1 = fs.readFileSync('file1.xsd');
const file2 = fs.readFileSync('file2.xsd');

// Parse the XSD files using xml2js
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();
let xsd1, xsd2;

parser.parseString(file1, (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  xsd1 = result;
});

parser.parseString(file2, (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  xsd2 = result;
});

findMissingElements(xsd1[schema], xsd2[schema]);

const builder = new xml2js.Builder();
const updatedXsd = builder.buildObject(xsd1);

fs.writeFileSync('file-updated.xsd', updatedXsd);

function findMissingElements(schema1, schema2) {
  const elementsToAdd = [];

  // Check all top-level elements in schema2
  for (const element2 of schema2[element] || []) {
    const element1 = schema1[element]?.find((e) => e.$.name === element2.$.name);
    if (!element1) {
      elementsToAdd.push(element2);
    } else {
      // Check nested elements and types
      const cType = element2[complexType];
      if (cType) {
        if (element2[complexType][0]?.[sequence]?.[0]) {
          delete element1['$']['type']; // to remove type attribute (if any) from elements which are complex types
          element1[complexType] = element1[complexType] || [{}];
          element1[complexType][0][sequence] = element1[complexType][0][sequence] || [{}];
          element1[complexType][0][sequence][0][element] = element1[complexType][0][sequence][0][element] || [];
          element1[complexType][0][sequence][0][element].push(...findMissingElements(element1[complexType][0][sequence][0], element2[complexType][0][sequence][0]));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return elementsToAdd;
}
```